# How to make timer using coroutine in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make 2 minute timer for my game using coroutine. Its starts to backcount from biginning of the game. Everything working nice until reaching 1 minute. After that something is going wrong (I suppose the mistake is in `yield` command, because when I'm debugging the code, it throws in that line).

**The Error:**
There is the link with link to GIF showing error:
https://giphy.com/gifs/Pk8t1StrR8dmip30NN

```
private int seconds;
private int minutes = 1;

void Start()
{
    seconds = 59;
    timer.text = "2:00";
    StartCoroutine(CountSeconds());
}

IEnumerator CountSeconds() 
{
    while (true)
    {

        seconds--;

        if (seconds >= 10)
        {
            timer.text = $"{minutes} : {seconds}";
        }
        else 
        {
            timer.text = $"{minutes} : 0{seconds}";

            if (seconds == 0)
            {
                seconds = 59;
                minutes--;
            }
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}
```

}

Please, help me to resolve this absurde problem.

Comment: Dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76117595/how-to-can-make-timer-using-coroutine-in-unity-c

Comment: how to delete that questiot?I aked earlier

Comment: There should be a delete button/link - I think somewhere where the "edit" etc links are.

Comment: Not mine)))) this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76117595/how-to-can-make-timer-using-coroutine-in-unity-c)

Comment: If that is your account, you need to login as that user first, then you can delete it.

Comment: It isn't my account. He copied my question

Comment: In that case, you should flag it with "moderator intervention needed" or something similar.

Comment: I flagged it for plagiarization. I guess some moderator will investigate. They would have means to know which one is the original.

Comment: Meanwhile: Posting images of errors is frowned upon. Can you add it as text?

Comment: If you payed attention to that time when the question asked, it'll be visible that I asked earlier. So I flagged that answer too

Comment: I meant I flagged that other Question. I am trying to help here.

Comment: I understood. Meanwhile @Thịnh is sitting in front of his computer and can't understand why his question got negative vote))

Comment: About error's picture: English isn't my first language, so I decided that it'll be better to provide error's description as picture

Answer (score 0):

I would approach it a bit differently and use a TimeSpan to countdown the minutes since it would make everything a bit easier.

```
private TimeSpan timeLeft = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);

void Start()
{
    timer.text = timeLeft.ToString("mm\:ss");
    StartCoroutine(CountSeconds());
}

IEnumerator CountSeconds() 
{
    while (true)
    {
        //I am reducing the time left on the counter by 1 second each time.
        timeLeft = timeLeft.Subtract(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
        timer.text = timeLeft.ToString("mm\:ss");

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for a thorough answer. What should I replace in ("mm\:ss")?

Comment: The "mm\:ss" in ToString is there to format the time in a 00:00 (minute:second) format. If you dont want the leading 0 in the minutes try "m\:ss". If you want to format it to something else you can check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings and find the format that you would like.

Answer (score 0):

check you Text, Does it can show 0:59 or 0:58? or make sure do you have other logic use the text, it looks like when secnods == 0 then set it to 59 but next loop it-- set to 58, 0:59 haved jumped. you may use when you start record var  startime = Time.time; when you need seconds-- ,use senconds - (Time.time - startTime) instead;